# multiple query en nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, mvc, express

Quiero mostrar un post y los respectivos comentarios para esto tengo 2 tablas en `mysq`l una "**post**" y la otra "**comentarios**"

Uso `mcv` modelo vista controlador con `nodejs` y `express`.

```
model.js
getOne(id, cb) {
conn.query('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?', id, cb);
}

controller.js 
getOne(req, res, next) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);

    bm.getOne(id, (err, data) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.render('detalles', {
                c: data
            });
        }
    });
}

router.js
router.get('/detalles/:id',bc.getOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta no es muy clara, pero creo que lo que necesitas se podria hacer utilizando el modulo async y utilizando la funcion async.waterfall para realizar  varios querys en cascada y serviria si el query secundario depende del valor del primer query.

Seria algo como esto :

```
console.log('Program Start');
var async = require('async');
async.waterfall([
  function (callback) {
    console.log('First Step --> ');
    callback(null, '1', '2');
  },
  function (arg1, arg2, callback) {
    console.log('Second Step --> ' + arg1 + ' ' + arg2);
    callback(null, '3');
  },
  function (arg1, callback) {
    console.log('Third Step --> ' + arg1);
    callback(null, 'final result');
  }
  ], function (err, result) {
   console.log('Main Callback --> ' + result);
});

       console.log('Program End');
```

Saludos